# How to display a custom field in the order review page of checkout of WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Is it possible to insert the field multiple local pickup in order review template of WooCommerce?

Answer (score 3):

From my article on [adding custom checkout fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/517/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) here's some sample code on how to display the order data. You will need to find out what the meta keys are for the data you wish to display.

```
// display the extra data on order recieved page and my-account order review
function kia_display_order_data( $order_id ){  ?>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Additional Info' ); ?></h2>
    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive additional_info">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><?php _e( 'Some Field:' ); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, '_some_field', true ); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><?php _e( 'Another Field:' ); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, '_another_field', true ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'kia_display_order_data', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'kia_display_order_data', 20 );


// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function kia_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){  ?>
    <div class="order_data_column">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Extra Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h4>
        <?php 
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Some field' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Another field' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_another_field', true ) . '</p>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'kia_display_order_data_in_admin' );
```